# Change decimal float character

Tags: php

I have a variable `$num='1.000,00';` which is ONE THOUSAND in europe.

I would like to get 20% of this number `$num*0.2;`, but i get wrong results since there is dot used in the string instead of comma.

I tried the `number_format` function but converted my thousand to 1 instead of 1000.

I would like a final result back in european form after the percentage is calculated. (200,00).

Comment: Did you intend to define your `$num` as a string instead of a number?

Comment: I cant do anything with the $num. Its from the other source an i have to accept it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num = '1.000,50';

echo floatval(str_replace(array('.', ','), array('', '.'), $num)) * .2;
```

### Edit after comment Axel

You can better work with floats. Why use strings? Use the real floats for all the math operations and transform the float to the whished format when viewing it to the user.

Like so:

```
$val = 1000.20;
$new_val = $val * .2;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'nl_NL');
echo money_format('%(#10n', $new_val);
```

Results in `EUR 200,04`

More info [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Comment: Valid for Germany, not for France or Swiss, where it is "1 000,30" and not for UK where it is "1,000.50" - all Europe. Use monetary conversion function with a proper locale instead of fiddling around with single characters. Functions like that should go in to some centralized utilities lib and `wrap` the native language functions.

Comment: True, I think the best way is, to work with real floats in the system (why store it as strings?) and use that for operations and format the values to the wished valuta format in views. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = str_replace(array('.', ','), array('', '.'), $num);
```